# Database size MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, database, size

I have two database: DB_1Large  and DB_2Medium

- DB_1Large.mdb have size 50 gb
- DB_2Medium.mdb have size 16 gb

### Problem:

Its look ridiculous, but backup of this databases have next sizes:

- DB_1Large.bak - ~30 gb
- DB_2Medium - ~12 gb

And after compress with win rar or studio this have next sizes:

- DB_1Large.bak - ~2.5 gb
- DB_2Medium - ~5.5 gb

Why and how can I make it smaller?

**Exec sp_spaceused for both databases:**

```
database_name   database_size   unallocated space   
DB_1Large   52349.38 MB 20197.74 MB 
reserved    data    index_size  unused
30546184 KB 16273760 KB 13500336 KB 772088 KB

database_name   database_size   unallocated space   
DB_2Medium  17144.19 MB 4672.13 MB  
reserved    data    index_size  unused
12457024 KB 10608232 KB 1809120 KB  39672 KB
```

Comment: Please show us the result of sp_spaceused for both databases

Comment: >>>how can I make it smaller<<< use WITH COMPRESSION in your backup command if your Edition supports it

Comment: @sepupic I edit my question, i write sizes AFTER compression, sorry

Comment: @ Андрій Петрук, I asked you about so_spaceused results that you did not publish yet

Comment: @sepupic I'm update question

Comment: As I already answered, your backups (that are not compressed) reflect your db DATA size. Look at the RESERVED and UNALLOCATED. Your first db has 30Gb of used space and 20Gb of unallocated, so the backup has 30Gb size. Your second db has 12Gb of used space and 18Gb are unallocated, so the backup size is 12Gb

Comment: @sepupic Yes, this I understand, but why second database have larger size after compression?

Comment: I answered on this too. You need to investigate win rar's compression algorithm to figure it out. I know only page and row compression algorithms of SQL Server, so I can explain why one table can be compressed and other can not, but I'm not interested in win rar's algorithm so I have no idea what it compresses better

Answer (score 0):

Here COMPRESSION is Specified at the time backup,it will compress the database and take backup

```
Use master
Go
BACKUP DATABASE [DatabaseName] 
TO  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\DatabaseName_2017-08-07.bak' 
WITH  COPY_ONLY, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  
NAME = N'SqlClass-Full Database Backup', 
SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 5
GO
```

Comment: Enterprise Edition only, right? (+ Standard starting with 2017)

Comment: i am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - Developer Edition

Comment: Developer = Enterprise features, but different licensing

Comment: And why on the earth do you suggest to take a copy_only backup?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't use `COMPRESSION` option, your databases have 30Gb and 12Gb of data accordingly. Backup backs up only data and not the empty space.

If you are interested in win rar compression ratio maybe you'd better search for its compression algorithm, maybe your second backup just is more "compressible" due to repeating combination of bytes

Comment: I'm trying winrar and COMPRESSION option, same for both databases.. and result be identicaly

Comment: @Андрій Петрук, I already said, I can imagine that 000000000000001111111111111111 data can be better compressed than 01001000100001000001, so if you are really interested in, look for win rar's algorithm, open your backup files in binary editors and compare them

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.NAME
,ROUND(SUM(CAST(mf.size AS bigint)) * 8 / 1024, 0) Size_MBs
,(SUM(CAST(mf.size AS bigint)) * 8 / 1024) / 1024 AS Size_GBs
FROM sys.master_files mf
INNER JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = mf.database_id
WHERE d.database_id > 4 -- Skip system databases if you want
GROUP BY d.NAME
ORDER BY d.NAME
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**